# Looking for the origin of a possibly idiomatic German phrase, 'schnapp-shnoot'

Tags: phrase, idiom, dialect

My maternal grandparents were Germans who grew up in German-speaking communities of Russia, hence their dialect might vary substantially from German as it is spoken in Germany. My mom one day recently referred to our dog as 'schnap-shnoot' (a phonetic rendition), which she translated as 'smart-nose.' But I can't find anything about it on any German language translation sites. It sounds vaguely Yiddish to me, but I couldn't find anything like it on Yiddish sites either. Is this even a real phrase? Or could it be some kind of English hybrid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's most likely German:

Your mom literally called the dog a "snappy snout".

*"schnappen"* is very straightforward - *"to snap"* in the sense of *"biting"*, *"grabbing"* or *"nipping"*.

*"Schnut"* is a dialect version of *"Schnute* - a term with meaning of *"snout"*. It's a version used in the Danube Swabian dialect and this has a lot of similarities to Russian German as spoken in the small, isolated communities. Considering the context, I'm sure that is the case here as well.

If your mother gives a slightly different translation, remember that words always carry an abstract meaning and a dog that is quick to snap at something, can in English be called a *"smart ...".*

Comment: Thanks Stephie! I thought the phrase was funny and wanted to know more about it. My mom doesn't really know German, except phrases (like this one) she picked up from her parents.